# Computer not booting with single RAM stick. Could Dual Channel be required?

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, post

I have just recently ordered new computer parts. In the motherboard and CPU spec, only dual channel are specified. Does that mean my computer may not be able to post and boot normally because I am running it in Single-Channel and not Dual channel? I thought it would be able run in single channel, but I think I might be lacking a memory stick.

This is one 16GB stick. I already have tested the motherboard with 2x4GB sticks, but the computer did not boot with those either. Those are buffered and not unbuffered, and too slow for the CPU. 2666MHz are specified. I have tried with different kinds of setups, also a different PSU.

PSU:
350 watt

Ram sticks tested:
2133mhz Dual-Channel 2x4gb sticks DIMM

2x32gb UDIMM 3200mhz

1x16gb UDIMM 2666mhz

Motherboard:
UDIMM ECC/Non-ECC, up to 2933mhz. 2DPC.

CPU:
2666mhz memory.

Neither of the RAMs are actually 100% correct according to the specifications.

But I am also wondering if getting another stick of the 1x16gb which is identical and if I could run them as Dual-Channel even if both of them are Single-Channel?

Comment: I never heard of a motherboard which would not work with a single DIMM. I have run into boards which required a specific order of DIMMs into the memory slots.  If the manual does not list it, try all slots one by one.

Comment: The order is actually a little different from what I expected according to the manual, the first stick should be put in the second slot.  Could there be any other reasons why it is not starting? I have tried with two different PSUs as well, thought maybe it did not give enough watt.

The guide says it could be run with mixed RAM speeds, only the slowest would be used. Single channel are not specified by the specs. It is a workstation/server board by the way, not gaming.

Comment: It would have been nice to specify your motherboard model and RAM.

Comment: Please use [edit] to update your question with the info requested above.

Comment: No. It is a simple question. If the motherboard have specified 2DPC, could RAM sticks be required which are dual-channel? As I only have one RAM-stick which is single channel? It actually says 2x8gb on the stick. But it is a single stick of course. The components are all after 2020.

Comment: Added some more info in the post.